# Error cannot start Play! app

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

When I try to run play app I get the following error (this didn't happen before):

> `$ start 9010`
>   `[error] {file:/home/bogunovi/guesstiment/}guesstiment/compile:copy-resources: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/bogunovi/guesstiment/target/scala-2.9.1/classes/evolutions/default/1.sql (Permission denied)`

Oops, cannot start the server?

Comment: Are you sure you current user can open this file ? `/home/bogunovi/guesstiment/target/scala-2.9.1/classes/evolutions/default/1.sql` ?
Didn't you compile or check out your project with a different user ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although other guys suggested nobody gave a solution. Most probably some of previous start was done with other user or with `sudo`, so it created files which can't be read by current user, check it in terminal:

(use `sudo` if required)

```
ls -la  /home/bogunovi/guesstiment/target/scala-2.9.1/classes/evolutions/default
```

then you can [`chown`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chown) all files/folders to current user/group or just remove all generated files (ie. `sudo play clean`) and start application with current user.

Optionally you can continue with starting application with sudo, it will prevent other (non sudoers) to start it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you don't have permission for the file.
I guess user who start application is different from user who own it.
This is not about play, it's about linux file permission.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions